# org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; Document root element "session-factory", must match DOCTYPE root "hibernate-configuration"

Tags: java, mysql, xml, hibernate

Below is my configuration file used to used to connect to MySQl Db.

HibernateConf.cfg.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<session-factory>
<!--  connection to database -->
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/blrap</property>
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">oracle</property>

<!-- disable autocommit -->
<property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</property>

<!-- to display sql query generated while running the programme -->
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
<property name="format_sql">true</property>
<property name="use_sql_comments">true</property>

<!-- using for JDBC transaction -->
<property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>

<!-- for mapping -->
<mapping resource="cust.hbm.xml"/>
</session-factory>
```

I have tried changing the DOCTYPE referring the materials and solutions available on internet, but still getting below error. Is it because of Log4j jars as I am getting WARNING messages for that also ?

Error

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.logging).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: invalid configuration
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2160)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2077)
    at dao.CustomerDAO.insertInfo(CustomerDAO.java:12)
    at dao.CustomerDAO.main(CustomerDAO.java:35)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 5; columnNumber: 18; Document root element "session-factory", must match DOCTYPE root "hibernate-configuration".
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.rootElementSpecified(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2157)
    ... 3 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<hibernate-configuration>` is missing before `<session-factory>`, make use of below config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC  
      "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"  
      "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration><!--  Missing statement-->
<session-factory>
 <!--  connection to database -->
 <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
 <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/blrap</property>
 <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
 <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
 <property name="hibernate.connection.password">oracle</property>

 <!-- disable autocommit -->
 <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</property>

 <!-- to display sql query generated while running the programme -->
 <property name="show_sql">true</property>
 <property name="format_sql">true</property>
 <property name="use_sql_comments">true</property>

 <!-- using for JDBC transaction -->
 <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>

 <!-- for mapping -->
 <mapping resource="cust.hbm.xml"/>
</session-factory>
<hibernate-configuration>
```